# PySpark application creates many pyspark-shell sessions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have started working on Spark using Python. I'm working on an application that uses SparkML Linear Regression APIs. When I submit my job in YARN cluster mode, during the execution phase, many pyspark-shell apps get created with YARN as the user. I could see them in the YARN UI. They eventually get finished with succeeded status and my main application which I actually submitted then gets finished with succeeded status. Is this an expected behavior? This is kinda interesting to me since I create the singleton sparkSession instance and use it throughout my application so I don't know why pyspark-shell sessions/apps get created.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, seems to be happen for some scripts only

Comment: I met the same issue. Did you solve the issue @Sivaprasanna Sethuraman? That is how I start the session SparkSession.builder.appName("app-name").getOrCreate()

Answer (score 0):

The immediate solution would be to use sparkContext instead of sparkSession. But it would be interesting to see your configuration lines to see how you're creating your sessions to be able to tell why multiple apps are being created.

We just updated to Spark 2.2 from Spark 1.6, so we have yet to delve seriously into sparkSessions (which are new in 2+).